# Make sidebar fadein on scroll point

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Been researching some way to make my side navigation bar fadein on a specific area of my website. Just not sure how to go about it. I found some jquery that is around the problem. But being new to the stuff im not sure how to implement it into my specific code.

The example given is

```
if ($(window).scrollTop() >= "number of pixels") {
    if ($('"button plus number"').css('display') === 'none') {
        $('"button plus number"').fadeIn('slow');
        $('"button plus number"').prev().fadeOut();
        $('"button plus number"').next().fadeOut();
    }
}
```

So basically with my code I am wanting is to get .cbp-fbscroller to fade in or at least appear at about 900px. Also once i get an understanding of how it works I could then use the code to make other things fade in on scroll points as well.

Here is a basic fiddle so you guys can get the idea http://jsfiddle.net/vLf18Lbk/

HTML area for fadein:

```
<div class="main">   
    <div id="cbp-fbscroller" class="cbp-fbscroller">
        <nav>
            <a href="#fbsection1" class="cbp-fbcurrent">Section 1</a>
            <a href="#fbsection2">Section 2</a>
            <a href="#fbsection3">Section 3</a>
            <a href="#fbsection4">Section 4</a>
            <a href="#fbsection5">Section 5</a>
        </nav>
        <section id="fbsection1"></section>
        <section id="fbsection2"></section>
        <section id="fbsection3"></section>
        <section id="fbsection4"></section>
        <section id="fbsection5"></section>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS needing to fade in:

```
/* The nav is fixed on the right side  and we center it by translating it 50% 
(we don't know it's height so we can't use the negative margin trick) */
.cbp-fbscroller > nav {
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 9999;
    right: 100px;
    top: 50%;
    width: 26px;
    -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%);
    -moz-transform: translateY(-50%);
    -ms-transform: translateY(-50%);
    transform: translateY(-50%);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

your jQuery code is correct.
when you scroll to bottom more than 250px fade in "go to top", in other wise fade out "go to top"
you can check line 41 of javascript

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(document).on("scroll", onScroll);
    
    //smoothscroll
    $('a[href^="#"]').on('click', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $(document).off("scroll");
        
        $('a').each(function () {
            $(this).removeClass('active');
        })
        $(this).addClass('active');
      
        var target = this.hash,
            menu = target;
        $target = $(target);
        $('html, body').stop().animate({
            'scrollTop': $target.offset().top+2
        }, 500, 'swing', function () {
            window.location.hash = target;
            $(document).on("scroll", onScroll);
        });
    });
});

function onScroll(event){
    var scrollPos = $(document).scrollTop();
    $('#menu-center a').each(function () {
        var currLink = $(this);
        var refElement = $(currLink.attr("href"));
        if (refElement.position().top <= scrollPos && refElement.position().top + refElement.height() > scrollPos) {
            $('#menu-center ul li a').removeClass("active");
            currLink.addClass("active");
        }
        else{
            currLink.removeClass("active");
        }
    });
}

///// edit go to top
$(window).scroll(function() {
    if ($(this).scrollTop() > (250)) {
        $("#top").fadeIn('fast');
    } else{
        $("#top").fadeOut('fast');
    };
});


$("a[href='gototop']").click(function() {
  $("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, "slow");
  return false;
});
```

```css
body, html {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}
.menu {
    width: 100%;
    height: 75px;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 1);
    position: fixed;
    background-color:rgba(4, 180, 49, 0.6);
    -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease;
    -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease;
    -o-transition: all 0.3s ease;
    transition: all 0.3s ease;
}
.light-menu {
    width: 100%;
    height: 75px;
    background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 1);
    position: fixed;
    background-color:rgba(4, 180, 49, 0.6);
    -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease;
    -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease;
    -o-transition: all 0.3s ease;
    transition: all 0.3s ease;
}
#menu-center {
    width: 980px;
    height: 75px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
#menu-center ul {
    margin: 15px 0 0 0;
}
#menu-center ul li {
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0 30px 0 0;
    display: inline;
}
.active {
    font-family:'Droid Sans', serif;
    font-size: 14px;
    color: #fff;
    text-decoration: none;
    line-height: 50px;
}
a {
    font-family:'Droid Sans', serif;
    font-size: 14px;
    color: black;
    text-decoration: none;
    line-height: 50px;
}
#home {
    background-color: grey;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-image: url(images/home-bg2.png);
}
#portfolio {
    background-image: url(images/portfolio-bg.png);
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}
#about {
    background-color: blue;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}
#contact {
    background-color: red;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}
#top{
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 5px;
    right: 5px;
    background-color: #ffff00;
    cursor: pointer;
    display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="m1 menu">
    <div id="menu-center">
        <ul>
            <li><a class="active" href="#home">Home</a>

            </li>
            <li><a href="#portfolio">Portfolio</a>

            </li>
            <li><a href="#about">About</a>

            </li>
            <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a>

            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
<div id="home"></div>
<div id="portfolio"></div>
<div id="about"></div>
<div id="contact"></div>
<a href="gototop" id="top">go to top</a>
```

In the same way you can select each tag fade or appearance.

Comment: Im a bit confused as to what code to specifically edit. My menu already has a smooth scroll added to it. Surely I only edit from line 26?

Comment: you use wrong type of address, there is no "images" or " js" folder in http://jsfiddle.net/vLf18Lbk/ . please upload your entire project then i can see what is your problem .